# How to get uploaded file URL from Google Cloud Storage by Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm building Google App Script product that uploads pdf file to Google Cloud Storage and it worked very well (thanks to this [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage)). But I'm unable to get uploaded file URL.

This is my `uploadFileToGCS()` function:

```
function uploadFileToGCS() {

  var service = getService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log("Please authorize %s", service.getAuthorizationUrl());
    return;
  }

  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(params.DRIVE_FILE).getBlob();
  var bytes = blob.getBytes();

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=FILE'
    .replace("BUCKET", params.BUCKET_NAME)
    .replace("FILE", encodeURIComponent(params.FILE_PATH));

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    contentLength: bytes.length,
    contentType: blob.getContentType(),
    payload: bytes,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });

  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}
```

And the log of response: `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));`

```
19-05-29 21:28:19:726 PDT] {
  "kind": "storage#object",
  "id": "bucket_name/folder_name/file_name.pdf/1559190499625016",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/folder_name/file_name.pdf",
  "name": "folder_name/file_name.pdf",
  "bucket": "bucket_name",
  "generation": "1559190499625016",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "application/pdf",
  "timeCreated": "2019-05-30T04:28:19.624Z",
  "updated": "2019-05-30T04:28:19.624Z",
  "storageClass": "MULTI_REGIONAL",
  "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2019-05-30T04:28:19.624Z",
  "size": "101396",
  "md5Hash": "hash",
  "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o/folder_name/file_name.pdf?generation=1559190499625016&alt=media",
}
```

when I click to `mediaLink`, the browser automatically downloads my pdf file, that's not I want.

So how I can get uploaded URL file from Google Cloud Storage by GAS ?
Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Could you see this? https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-storage-signed-urls-in-apps-script-161b74a9c5e7 .

Comment: Thank you for your tutorial, but when I download JSON the credential from GCS, my json doesn't have `privateKey` and `client_email`? What I am missing?

Comment: Did you create a service account key using the GCP Console? See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: Thank you very much. I misunderstood. Could you give me an example of `baseURL` ?

Comment: I just downloaded my JSON from service account, it included `private_key` and `client_email` ...., an I pass my JSON as `credential ` and my pdf file url from Google Cloud Storage as `baseURL`, it generated signed URL, I opened that URL and I got this error `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.`

Comment: Never mind, it works now, thank you very much for your great tutorial !!!

Comment: @zkohi if you post your solution as an answer, I will absolutely upvote for your answer!

Comment: congratulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-storage-signed-urls-in-apps-script-161b74a9c5e7 .

And The docs to create a service account key using the GCP Console is https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys .

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial from @zkohi's answer is outdated and did not work for me.
I took the sample code from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually and rewrote it in JavaScript.

```js
function generate_signed_url(google_credentials, bucket_name, object_name,
                        subresource, expiration, http_method,
                        query_parameters, headers)
{
  if (expiration === undefined) expiration = 604800;
  if (http_method === undefined) http_method = 'GET';
  if (expiration > 604800) {
    throw new Error('Expiration Time can\'t be longer than 604800 seconds (7 days).');
  }
  
  var escaped_object_name = encodeURIComponent(object_name).replace(/%2[fF]/g, '/');
  var canonical_uri = '/' + escaped_object_name;

  var datetime_now = new Date();
  var request_timestamp = datetime_now.toISOString().replace(/\.\d\d\dZ$/, 'Z').replace(/[-:]/g, '');
  var datestamp = datetime_now.toISOString().replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/, '$1$2$3')

  var client_email = google_credentials.client_email;
  var credential_scope = datestamp + '/auto/storage/goog4_request';
  var credential = client_email + '/' + credential_scope;

  if (headers === undefined) headers = {};
  var host = bucket_name + '.storage.googleapis.com';
  headers['host'] = host;

  var ordered_headers = Object.entries(headers);
  ordered_headers.sort();
  var canonical_headers = ordered_headers.map(([k, v]) => k.toLowerCase() + ':' + v.toLowerCase() + '\n').join('');

  var signed_headers = ordered_headers.map(([k]) => k.toLowerCase()).join(';');

  if (query_parameters === undefined) query_parameters = {};
  query_parameters['X-Goog-Algorithm'] = 'GOOG4-RSA-SHA256';
  query_parameters['X-Goog-Credential'] = credential;
  query_parameters['X-Goog-Date'] = request_timestamp;
  query_parameters['X-Goog-Expires'] = expiration;
  query_parameters['X-Goog-SignedHeaders'] = signed_headers;
  if (subresource !== undefined) {
    query_parameters[subresource] = '';
  }

  var ordered_query_parameters = Object.entries(query_parameters);
  ordered_query_parameters.sort();
  var canonical_query_string = ordered_query_parameters.map(([k, v]) => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v)).join('&');

  var canonical_request = [http_method,
                           canonical_uri,
                           canonical_query_string,
                           canonical_headers,
                           signed_headers,
                           'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD'].join('\n');

  var canonical_request_hash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, canonical_request)
    .map(byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');

  var string_to_sign = ['GOOG4-RSA-SHA256',
                        request_timestamp,
                        credential_scope,
                        canonical_request_hash].join('\n');

  var signature = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(string_to_sign, google_credentials.private_key)
    .map(byte => ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');

  var scheme_and_host = 'https://' + host;
  var signed_url = scheme_and_host + canonical_uri + '?' + canonical_query_string + '&x-goog-signature=' + signature;

  return signed_url
}
```