# Copy data from download URL using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to App scripts and need help with copying the data to spreadsheet from URL.
However, URL is not a website but link which after clicking with directly download csv file into the computer. Also, its not ending with .csv as I have seen in other examples here.

URL basically coming to my inbox at a specific time. I'm trying to use Fetch URL but its not working at all.

Sample URL -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oPUPPUmy7psliSznUItT0DnHvilXwZHzyrmdyHpHi18/export?format=csv

```
function ABC () {

  const searchQuery = 'XYZ';
  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0,1);
  const urls = [];
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
        messages.forEach(message => {
    
        const body = message.getBody();

          var re = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'"".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;

          const match = body.match(re);
          if (match) { urls.push(match[1]); }
        });
  }) ;
  
    Logger.log(urls);

    url = urls.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","") ;
    Logger.log(url);

     function getData() {

    var attValue = '';

    // making a call to the target website
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

    //logging response from target website - In Script Editor > View > Logs
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());

    //parsing the response data from website
    //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response
    var rawData = response.getContentText();

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]);
    var cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
    cell.setValue(rawData);
}
 
};
```

Kindly help so that I can copy the data directly into spreadsheet or store the file in Google Drive with filename as combination of text and date.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly provide a sample **URL that isn't a website but link which after clicking with directly download CSV file into the computer** _(if possible)_ so people in the community will be able to fully replicate your actual script, that way your question will have a higher chance of getting an answer. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oPUPPUmy7psliSznUItT0DnHvilXwZHzyrmdyHpHi18/export?format=csv sample file

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

You can try the **tweaked script** below.

*In my understanding, here is your goal:*

1. Get your email messages that contain **URLs** *(CSV file)* via **"XYZ"** search terms.
2. Process the URL using **URLFetchApp** service
3. Place the CSV data into your second sheet tab.

> Note: If there's anything else missing or something may have been misunderstood, feel free to let me know.

### Tweaked Script

```
function ABC() {
  /**TWEAKED: Created a function call method called "getData" */
  const url = {
    getData: function () {
      const searchQuery = 'XYZ';
      const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 1);
      const urls = [];
      threads.forEach(thread => {
        const messages = thread.getMessages();
        messages.forEach(message => {

          const body = message.getBody();

          var re = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'"".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;

          const match = body.match(re);
          if (match) { urls.push(match[1]); }
        });
      });

      Logger.log(urls);

      /**TWEAKED: Instead of using the redundant replace method, 
       * used "regex" inside a single replace method to replace 
       * all [ and ] characters */
      var geturl = urls.toString().replace(/\[|]/gm, "");
      console.log(geturl)
      return geturl;
    }

  }

  var attValue = '';

  /**TWEAKED: Call the "url" variable's "getData" function that will return the URL */
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.getData.call());

  //logging response from target website - In Script Editor > View > Logs
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  //parsing the response data from website
  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response
  var rawData = response.getContentText();

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[1]);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  cell.setValue(rawData);
};
```

### Demonstration

> After running the **`ABC()`** function on the Apps Script editor, the **second sheet tab** gets populated with the CSV data:

[image]

> The Apps Script execution log view

[image]

## References:

- [JavaScript Function call()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp)

Comment: @AlokKumar You're welcome.  If this answer helps you, you may want to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended  to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I'm getting below error which might be due to security policies. I'm trying to use it for office related work.

Exception: Request failed for https://storage.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SecurityPolicyViolated</Code><Message>Request violates VPC Service Controls.</Message><Details>R... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: I see. I agree with you that this is due to access limitation as [stated on this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/errors#:~:text=This%20error%20(403)%20indicates%20that,Storage%20to%20make%20the%20request.). Is the actual URL you're using that doesn't work when you manually access it?

Comment: There is no issue while accessing the actual URL. CSV file get downloaded into system directly.

Comment: I see. Where is your actual `CSV` file hosted? I suppose it is not hosted like on your sample file `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oPUPPUmy7psliSznUItT0DnHvilXwZHzyrmdyHpHi18/export?format=csv`.

Comment: It seems you need to setup an authorization credential on the Google Cloud Console, where your **CSV** file is also hosted _(I suppose it is stored in your org's Google Cloud Storage)_ , then use that credential for the Google Apps Script to gain an authorization token to be able to access the `URL` without getting the `Error 403 exception`. For more context, see this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371944/how-to-get-uploaded-file-url-from-google-cloud-storage-by-google-app-script).